# How do I make my pygame character animations the same size if some of them are different sizes to start with?

Tags: python, animation, pygame, drawing

At the moment I am trying to code in a jump animation for my game. I've managed to get the jumping animation working but the images are at a different size to my other animations. The animations are all fine except for the sizes. I got the character I was going to use from [this](https://opengameart.org/content/2d-game-character-pack-slim-version) link.

Here is my code for loading the animations:

```
player_size = (80, 80)
for n in range(0, 10):
    img_right = pygame.image.load(f'img/Character animations/Jump Start/Jump Start_{n}.png').convert_alpha()
    img_right = pygame.transform.smoothscale(img_right, player_size)
    img_left = pygame.transform.flip(img_right, True, False)
    self.images_jump_start_right.append(img_right)
    self.images_jump_start_left.append(img_left)
for n in range(0, 12):
    img_right = pygame.image.load(f'img/Character animations/Idle/Idle_{n}.png').convert_alpha()
    img_right = pygame.transform.smoothscale(img_right, player_size)
    img_left = pygame.transform.flip(img_right, True, False)
    self.images_idle_right.append(img_right)
    self.images_idle_left.append(img_left)
for n in range(0, 16):
    img_right = pygame.image.load(f'img/Character animations/Walk/Walk_{n}.png').convert_alpha()
    img_right = pygame.transform.smoothscale(img_right, player_size)
    img_left = pygame.transform.flip(img_right, True, False)
    self.images_run_right.append(img_right)
    self.images_walk_left.append(img_left)
```

This is what the character looks like when [jumping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhCH8.png) at the moment. This is what the character looks like [normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvudL.png).

I've tried to change the size of the jump images separate to the other images, but it is either the same size or much bigger.

Does anyone have any ideas on what is the problem?

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You must use one scaling  factor for all images.

Define a scaling factor (e.g.: 0.5):

```py
image_scale = 0.5
```

Write a function that scales an image by a scaling factor:

```py
def scale_surface(surf, scale):
    width = round(surf.get_width() * scale)
    height = round(surf.get_height() * scale)
    return pygame.transform.smoothscale(surf, (width, height))
```

Use the function and scale factor to scale all images. e.g.:

```py
img_right = scale_surface(img_right, image_scale)
```